# Block Keyboard Inputs in html pages using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have a `<div>` .

```
<div id="ViewActivitydiv" >
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("QuestionAnswers", new { activityQuestionAnswersList = Model.ActivityQuestionAnswers?.ToList() })
</div>
```

My requirement is for this `<div>` , I should not allow User to use Keyboard shortcuts or tabs  or pointers using Keyboard.

I tried `tabindex="-1"`, But issue is the Component model is in different page and did not work for all controls in component models.

Can any one help me doing this ?

Comment: Show us the index.cshtml for that View Component .....

Comment: If tab-index did not work for you, are you able to use a JS-based solution? You could use `onfocus` or the jQuery .focus() event handler and call another object to focus instead. It's a JS hack, but it might work if your script is loaded across both views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work for all keyboard and mouse inputs :

```js
$("#ViewActivitydiv").on("keydown keypress keyup click contextmenu", false);
```

```css
#ViewActivitydiv {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ViewActivitydiv">test</div>
```

Comment: The 'click' and 'contextmenu' events shouldn't be necessary as 'pointer-events' is set to 'none'.